# Setting up the basic Java code

Tags: java, class, methods

I was wondering if you guys can help me set up my basic code because I know I can do it once I get the structure set up I should be able to get the rest.

If you can help me set it up maybe explain why your setting up the way you are. Or what is called what. My teacher explains it but I can't remember what video it was and they were all like 15minutes each.

So I need the following:
Build a class named Roulette with a method named betOnce that takes a console Scanner and an integer as parameters and that allows the user to make a bet about the integer

The betOnce method should prompt the user for which bet they want to make and should then report the number and whether the user won or lost.

Then build a driver class (named whatever you would like) that creates and uses an instance of the other class in order to play the game.  The main method will look something like this

So from what I understand it should look like this, maybe stop me where I get it wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class Roulette
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   Random r = new Random(); 
   int number = r.nextInt(37); 
   gameRunner.betOnce(in, number); 
}

 public Roulette()
 {
   public betOnce
   {


   }

}
```

}

Also I did try it like this and I'm guessing it's wrong I'm not sure why tho. It compiles like this but when I try to run it nothing happens even though I have something being printed out in the betOnce.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the reason as to why it is not running is because you are not printing anything to the screen. Another thing is that, in your method gameRunner, it should look like this

```
public static void gameRunner(*type* variableName, *type* variableName)
{

}
```

You aren't declaring any variable types in that method. Secondly, to get user input, you have to do something like this:

```
int n = scannerVariable.nextInt();
```

This will let the user input a number.

For some good beginners material, I would look at the book: Building Java programs, and going on the website practise it and practising their set of problems.

(updated code)

```
import java.util.*;
public class Roulette 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random r = new Random();
        int number = r.nextInt(37);
        BetOnce.gameRunner(in, number);
    }
}

class BetOnce
{
    public void gameRunner(Scanner in, int number)
    {
        //Code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to read the instructions **carefully**:

> Build a class named Roulette with a method named betOnce that takes a console Scanner and an integer as parameters

You created a class Roulette. And it contains a method named betOnce(). But your method doesn't take anything as argument, although the instructions say that it must take a Scanner and an int.

> Then build a driver class (named whatever you would like)

I don't see any other class in your code.

> that creates and uses an instance of the other class in order to play the game

That implies that you must create a new Roulette to call the betOnce() method. There is no need to create an instance if the method is static anyway. So the betOnce() method should not be static.

Comment: Ok aside from the formatting being off does that look right?

Comment: Well, read my answer. It says absolutely nothing about the formatting. It says that your betOnce method signature is wrong, that you must have 2 classes instead of one, and that the betOnce() method must not be static. That has nothing to do with formatting. Read. Carefully. Reading carefully will save you tons of time and mistakes.

Comment: OH sorry forgot to mention I updated the code, and I hurried and added it so the formatting was off.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. So no, it's not OK. You're confusing classes and methods. And you still don't have a second driver class containing your main method.